# How to increase the number of hashing rounds for /etc/shadow?

Tags: password, pam, hash

I usually use long passwords for my machines, but I heard that it's possible to increase the number of hashing rounds and get the same security with a shorter one. How would I make my system use more rounds when hashing the password?

Answer (score 7):

The number of rounds can be set by modifying the file `/etc/pam.d/common-password`. The relevant line is the one containing the `pam_unix.so` module. Add `rounds=<n>` at the end of the line to use `<n>` rounds for subsequent password changes.

Verify the setting by adding a user, e.g., by doing `adduser test1`. After adding the user, the `/etc/shadow` file should contain a line starting with `test1:$6$rounds=<n>$...`. Don't forget to delete the test user afterwards (`deluser test1`).

If everything looks good, change the passwords for all relevant users to apply the increased number of rounds to their hashes.

More information on pam_unix parameters can be found in the man page (`man pam_unix`).